# Use static ips for AWS Application Load Balancers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, aws-application-load-balancer

Our requirement is to

1. Assign static IPs to an ALB, because many of our customers have whitelisted it in their firewalls.
2. The X-Forwarded-For HTTP header should contain the clients IP address, because we have a https://www.whatismyip.com/ like service running which thousands of our IOT devices already use.

Tried following solution but it does not do #2, we see the internal NLB ip instead of the client IP in the X-FF
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/

Is there any load balancer out there that can do #1 and #2 or can AWS make this happen on request? Any help/pointers appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> AWS Global Accelerator lets you associate regional resources, such as load balancers and EC2 instances, to two static IP addresses.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/

Originally, Global Accelerator did not preserve the IP address of the client, but a subsequent enhancement made that possible.

> **Client IP Address Preservation**
>
> Today we are announcing an important new feature for AWS Global Accelerator. If you are routing traffic to an Application Load Balancer, the IP address of the user’s client is now available to code running on the endpoint.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-client-ip-address-preservation-for-aws-global-accelerator/

With this feature, the behavior of `X-Forwarded-For` is correct because the ALB sees the client IP.

This also has the potential to improve end-to-end performance, because the static addresses assigned to you from Global Accelerator are anycast routed from the Internet to a number of edge locations on the AWS Edge Network (where global services CloudFront and Route 53 live, though Global Accelerator does not directly use either of those services; by contrast, some other edge services like S3 Transfer Acceleration and "Edge Optimized" API Gateway actually use CloudFront under the hood).  From ingress at the edge, the traffic rides AWS fiber to the region of your ALB, and responses ride back to the edge and out to the viewer, eliminating some of the variability and vagaries of the public Internet.

This description seems like an impossibility and/or magic to those familiar with how networking and NAT typically work (and are constrained) but the secret sauce is an interconnection with the VPC network through an internal AWS service called Hyperplane, which also allows Network Load Balancers and NAT Gateways to work their magic with address translation and stateful flows.

This is the only official way to have static IPv4 addresses on the outside of an ALB with correct `X-Forwarded-For` handling and is well-suited to environments where there is an inflexible requirement for static addresses, due to factors outside your control.

The "two" static addresses mentioned above are for redundancy.  Two will be assigned.  You don't strictly need to use both of them, but it's best if you do.

Comment: Thanks Michael this is news to us! We tried this in Jul 2019 and the X-FF didn't show the client IP address will give it a shot again.

Comment: Ok we tested it and the X-FF works with the Global Accelerator (GA) after turning on the "Preserve client IP ". But it still does not solve my first requirement (#1) as below. 
 I want to assign a "pre-existing" static elastic IP (from the AWS pool) which our customers have already whitelisted in their firewalls as one of the IP of the GA. Is that allowed or something being worked in near term?

Comment: @rindshegs I don't speak for Amazon, of course, and I don't have any insider info on this, but that seems very unlikely to happen, due to simple technical infeasibility.  Global Accelerator uses IP addresses that are advertised to the Internet using a very different strategy than Elastic IP addresses -- there are multiple, globally-dispersed black boxes that will all respond to traffic sent to your assigned IPs and shuttle it back to your VPC.   Porting EIPs into this scenario seems impossible since they are fully under the control of one region.

Comment: The only other solution that comes to mind would be to deploy HAProxy on EC2 behind a Network Load Balancer.  I actually prefer HAProxy over ALB since it provides superior logging (multiple timers and better error cause information, logged in real time).  It's technically solid, as HAProxy can handle massive traffic on small machines, but it probably boils down to a question of how much infrastructure you want to maintain.